# Writing to CSV file into a cell

Tags: python, export-to-csv

My current code write to CSV into multiple cells (see screen shot)

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib
url = 'https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1346734-REG/canon_eos_6d_mark_ii.html'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='js-productHighlights product-highlights c28 fs14 js-close')
bullets = content.find_all('li', class_='top-section-list-item')
csv_file = open('book2.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow (['headline'])
for bullet in bullets:
     headline = (bullet.string)
     csv_writer.writerow ([headline])

csv_file.close()
```

How do i write to excel into a single cell?

desired output will be - cell A1 will have all the text that variable 'headline' holds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through all `bullets` and writing each one in csv file like you are now:

```
for bullet in bullets:
     headline = (bullet.string)
     csv_writer.writerow ([headline])
```

you should probably just write a single row with sanitized `bullets` variable content. Not completely sure how your content looks like, but try something like this:

```
# your other code...
bullets = content.find_all('li', class_='top-section-list-item')
csv_file = open('book2.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow (['headline'])
# don't loop, instead join values with new line
csv_writer.writerow(['\015'.join([bullet.string for bullet in bullets])])    
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Nop, not working. it writes single character per cell after applying your code

Comment: Ah, right, I got 2 mistakes :the first one was not using `[]` in `writerow()` (that's why everything got separated) and the second one is using literal new line `\n` instead of adding it as a part of the single string you'd like to insert into the cell. I updated my answer now, try it out!

Comment: Another update with escape character which will render out new lines in a single cell (`\015` instead of new line `\n`).